# Multiple switch cases design pattern

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have multiple switch statements

```
switch(condition1)
{
 case 1:
  doSomething;
  break;

 case 2: 
  doSomething;
  break;

 default
  break;
}
```

--

```
 switch(condition2)
 {
  case 1:
   doSomething;
   break;

 case 2: 
  doSomething;
  break;

 default
  break;
 }
```

The conditions can increase in future eg. condition3, condition4 i.e more switch statements can be there. So i need scalability.

I want to merge these switch statements. 
I dont want to use alot of if,else conditions. 
No return statments in between to break the flow. 
No dynamic memory allocation.
No Multi-dimensional arrays.

eg.

```
result = someOperation(condition1, condition2, condition3...)

switch(result)
{
  case 1:
   doSomething;
   break;

 case 2: 
  doSomething;
  break;

 default
  break;

}
```

Specifically, i want to generate unique combination of multiple ints.
Don't want string comparisons.
I prefer to hide entire functionality in some design pattern ( i was not able to find one, though.)

Comment: The strategy pattern is suitable for this situation

Comment: As FatGaint said use strategy pattern. link: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Comment: Also the State Design Pattern might be a good approach.

Comment: Strategy pattern will work, but how will i choose which strategy to choose. The result = someOperation(condition1, condition2, condition3...), what will be the someOperation which will give unique number, to choose strategy from a result.

Comment: Do you need to invoke all the conditions at one shot?

Comment: Are your conditions mutually exclusive ?

Answer (score 1):

> The conditions can increase in future eg. condition3, condition4 i.e more switch statements can be there. So i need scalability.
>
> [comment:] Strategy pattern will work, but how will i choose which strategy to choose.

Consider this:

```
class operation // strategy base
{
public:
    virtual bool applies(int result) const = 0;
    virtual void perform() = 0;
    virtual ~operation() = 0;
};

class first_case: public operation // choose better name than first_case
{
public:
    bool applies(int result) const override
    {
        return result == 1; // equivalent of "case 1:"
    }
};

// other cases defined here
```

Client code:

```
void do_stuff()
{
    // std::vector<std::unique_ptr<operation>> operations; defined else-where

    auto result = someOperation(condition1, condition2, condition3...);

    for(auto &op: operations) // equivalent of your switch above
        if(op.applies(result))
        {
            op.perform();
            break;
        }
}
```

Basically, you implement the strategy choosing criteria as a virtual API on the operation base (and specialize it for each operation).

Comment: How do we find the result ?  auto result = someOperation(condition1, condition2, condition3...); The someOperation is unknown, which will give unique number based on which strategy will be chosen.

Comment: I do not know (this depends exclussively on what you are actually implementing). For example, if your strategy was to implement an arithmetical expression evaluator, your operation would be associated with the relevant input being '+', '-' and so on. When you do find your criteria, it would be better implemented in `operation::applies` specializations, not in `someOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

if you need something scalable, perhaps you can implement some kind of table, indexed by condition result, that stores a pointer to the function to be called on behalf of the condition result.  This way you'll get something scalable (you can modify the table dynamically, at runtime) and efficient (well, not as efficient as a `switch` statement, but perhaps enough for your purposes)

In case you have to add new code for the conditions (or the last paragraph solution is not efficient enough), the most effective thing is to write a little program that generates the `switch` statements for you (and perhaps `#include` it on the proper place), and include this generation in the automatic building process.